# combination problem gre @

Tags: combinations, gre-exam

On the new years Eve , every member of a community exchanged cards with every other member. if a total of 420 different cards were exchanged , then how many different members were there in the community ?

but my answwer is wrong

I did it in this way

like there are five member

A B C D F

A=4

B=3

C=2

D=1

total no the cards exchanged =10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are $n$ members, each will send $n-1$ cards.  So the total cards sent is
$$
n(n-1)=420
$$
$$
n^2 - n -420 = 0
$$
$$
(n-21)(n+20) = 0
$$
So $n$ is $21$ (since it obviously needs to be positive).

Note that if A and B "exchange cards,"  2 different cards are exchanged, not 1.  If the problem said 420 pairs of people exchanged cards, then the answer would have been 41.

Answer (score 0):

The key word here is **exchanged**.  That implies that for each pair of members, say person $A$ and person $B$, there are **two** cards that switch hands:  $A$ gives a card to $B$, and $B$ gives a card to $A$.  Your counting method assumes that there is only a single card transferred between each pair of people.

Answer (score 0):

let say there are 3 people A,B,C. Combinations possible will be 3C2 = 3 (AB,AC,BC) and there will be 6 cards exchanged i.e 3C2 x 2 ...Similarly if n people are there combinations possible will be nC2 and cards exchanged = nC2 x 2...But nC2 x 2 = 420 .. nC2 = 210...n(n-1)=420..Hence answer will be 21

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Please see [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how you can better format mathematics on this site and then edit your post accordingly.